# Changing length of time / duration that an object takes to complete rotations in octave / matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I can create a rotating sphere but how can I have it complete 2 rotations, 3.5 rotations or x rotations in a specific amount of time like 3 seconds, 25.4 seconds or x seconds?

Code below:

```
% Using rotate
clear all,clf reset,tic,clc, close all
figure
[x,y,z] = sphere(270);

s = surf(x,y,z,z,'EdgeColor','none');
axis vis3d
for ang = 1:360
    rotate(s,[1,1,1],1)
    str_1=strcat('Angle= ', sprintf('%02d',(ang)),'---------','Time in Seconds= ', sprintf('%02d',(toc)));
    title({str_1});

    xlabel('X-axis')
    ylabel('Y-axis')
    zlabel('Z-axis')
    drawnow
end
```

[image: Rotating sphere]

Ps: I'm using Octave 5.1 which is like Matlab

Comment: For most questions which involve having fine control over the timing I recommend to use a [`timer`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html).

Comment: This will depend on how long your PC takes to render each frame. You could use `pause` inside the loop to pause for `(T/N)/360` seconds, for total time `T` and total rotations `N`. However, you'll never be able to precisely account for the rendering time each frame.

Comment: If you time each iteration, then you can change the wait times, but also the "framerate" or amount of angles you will plot.

Comment: If you are using Octave, then tag Octave, not MATLAB. A MATLAB solution would likely not work for you in Octave, especially in the graphics department, Octave is significantly lagging behind innovations in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use a [`timer`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html)

As said in the comments, the only way to have some form of control over the timing in MATLAB is to use their `timer` class. Even that is limited, Mathworks state explicitely that you cannot expect a precision under the millisecond.

The following code gets close to what you asked. It creates a timer which trigger every `period` and execute a function (which will rotate the sphere).

The trick is to define the `period` (called `TimeIncrement` in the code) and the angular rotation step so that the motion is fluid and achieved in the target time.

Even with a timer, and especially for low target time, it won't be accurate to the millisecond. I set up a `minTimeIncrement` (based on my machine), which is used to relax the number of rotations (*increase the angular step*) in case the `TimeIncrement` is not enough to render one rotation. You may have to adjust it for your own machine.

```
%% Create and display the sphere
clear all,clf reset,clc, close all
figure
[x,y,z] = sphere(270) ;
s = surf(x,y,z,z,'EdgeColor','none');
axis vis3d
xlabel('X-axis')
ylabel('Y-axis')
zlabel('Z-axis')

%% Parameters
minTimeIncrement = 0.040 ;  % I worked that out on my machine.
                            % You may have to adjust for your

TotalRotationTime = 3.5 ;   % in second
Nangles = 360 ;             % number of angle rotations to complete a full turn

TimeIncrement    = TotalRotationTime / Nangles ; % Time step between each rotation
AngularIncrement = 360 / Nangles ;               % angle to rotate at each iteration

% Here we make sure to respect the timing. If the number of rotation
% increment does not fit into the total time allowed, the rotation increments
% are extended so they will be less of them.
if TimeIncrement < minTimeIncrement
    warning('Period too small, the angle increment will be adjusted')
    TimeIncrement = minTimeIncrement ;
    Nangles = TotalRotationTime / TimeIncrement ;
    AngularIncrement = 360 / Nangles ;               % angle to rotate at each iteration
end

%% Create the timer and start it
t = timer ;
t.ExecutionMode = 'fixedRate' ;
t.Period   = TimeIncrement ;
t.TimerFcn = @(htimer,evt) UpdateSphere(htimer,evt,s,AngularIncrement) ;
t.StopFcn  = 'delete(t)' ; % for self cleanup
start(t) ;
```

**Edit:** Sorry just realised I forgot to post the code for the callback function. The code for `UpdateSphere.m`:

```
function UpdateSphere( ht , evt , s , ang_increment )
%UpdateSphere Rotate the sphere and update the title display

%% Define a few persistent variables
persistent currentAngle ;
persistent StartTime ;

%% Initialise or update persistent variables
if isempty(currentAngle)
    currentAngle = 0 + ang_increment ;
% else
%     currentAngle = currentAngle + ang_increment ;
end
if isempty(StartTime)
    StartTime = tic ;
end

%% do the rotation
% To insure we will not go over 360 degrees
ang_increment = min(ang_increment , 360 - currentAngle) ;
currentAngle = currentAngle + ang_increment ;

rotate(s,[1,1,1],ang_increment)
strTitle = sprintf('Angle = %5.1f ° / Time = %7.3f s',currentAngle,toc(StartTime)) ;
title(strTitle);
drawnow

%% Stop the timer and reset counter if we reached a full rotation
if currentAngle >= 360
    currentAngle = 0 ;
    StartTime = [] ;
    stop(ht) ;
end

end
```

[image]